# jquery fn.extend() returning values and call values in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, extend

I need some help in understanding something, that propably is easy for serious jquery and javascript programmers.

Lets say I have a code like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
   myNameSpace: {
     myPlugIn: function (o) { 
       var o = { variable : o.variable || false };

      var myfunction = function(v) {
      o.variable = v;
      };
      return {
         myfunction : myfunction
      };

    }
});
```

and now I am able to call that with:

```
x = new $.myNameSpace.myPlugIn({variable : 99}) ;
```

and then I call my function myfunction like this

```
x.myfunction(20);
```

I can understand that, now the question: how can I get the value of variable inside my plug in.

I tried something like `alert(x.o[variable]);` etc. but I just cant get it - It must be easy...

What I try to accomplish is a value I could call if something inside the plugin is finished, or calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the variables inside with your current code, unless you change it to:

```
var myfunction = function(v) {
    o.variable = v;
    return v;  //or o.variable
};

//...
x.myfunction(20)  //20;
```

---

**Added**

It seems like you are trying to make a plugin for jQuery. To create a plugin, you do not use `$.extend`. `$.extend` is only used to preset default settings. <sup>[[1]](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options)</sup> Normally this is [how you set up a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        getVar: function(){ 
            return $.extend({
                data: data,
            }, methods);
        },
        setVar: function(d){ 
            data = d;
            return methods;
        }
    },
    data = {};

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        //do stuff
        data = $.extend( data , options );

        return methods;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wv5QH/1/

Comment: thanks derek, but I can´t take out the function of my plugin, to make it public. Or did you mean, if I need a specific value, I should make a function for it, call it from outside and return the value - for example: 

    myotherfunction() {
       return o.variable;
    }

now I don´t understand how I can call it from outside like: 
    test = x.myotherfunction

Cheers.

Comment: @Andre - Actually, your code won't work because `$.extend` is used to [merge 2 objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: this was mented for the upper post: this is what I am trying to do, there are other Objects I need in `$.myNameSpace` - but I also need access to some of the first objects values inside, like o.variable in the example.

Comment: Yes, that´s kind of what I am trying to do - is there no way around that extra function "getVar". Thanks a lot for the hint !

Comment: @Andre - There must be a function returning the data because your variables inside are kept private.